# Excecuting make is creating object file in wrong folder

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to ubuntu and hence to make file. I have successfully created make file with folder structure. However, if I add the similar structure, I get an error.

I successfully executed make command and ran application with one main cpp file and two files (list_menu.cpp  and list_menu.h ) in sub folder cpp11_and_cpp14_menu

folder structure looks exactly like below where cpp11_and_cpp14.cpp has the main function.

```
../advancedcppproject/
    cpp11_and_cpp14.cpp
    Makefile

../advancedcppproject/cpp11_and_cpp14_menu
    list_menu.cpp  
    list_menu.h 

../advancedcppproject/multi_threading_example
    multi_threading.cpp  
    multi_threading.h
```

Make file contents are

```
cpp11_and_cpp14 : cpp11_and_cpp14.o ./multi_threading_example/multi_threading.o ./cpp11_and_cpp14_menu/list_menu.o
        g++ cpp11_and_cpp14.o ./multi_threading_example/multi_threading.o ./cpp11_and_cpp14_menu/list_menu.o -o cpp11_and_cpp14

cpp11_and_cpp14.o : cpp11_and_cpp14.cpp ./cpp11_and_cpp14_menu/list_menu.h ./multi_threading_example/multi_threading.h
        g++ -c cpp11_and_cpp14.cpp

./cpp11_and_cpp14_menu/list_menu.0 : ./cpp11_and_cpp14_menu/list_menu.cpp ./cpp11_and_cpp14_menu/list_menu.h
        g++ -c ./cpp11_and_cpp14_menu/list_menu.cpp

./multi_threading_example/multi_threading.o : ./multi_threading_example/multi_threading.cpp ./multi_threading_example/multi_threading.h
        g++ -c ./multi_threading_example/multi_threading.cpp
```

After executing make command, it fails with an error message

```
g++ -c ./multi_threading_example/multi_threading.cpp 
g++ cpp11_and_cpp14.o ./multi_threading_example/multi_threading.o ./cpp11_and_cpp14_menu/list_menu.o -o cpp11_and_cpp14
g++: error: ./multi_threading_example/multi_threading.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'cpp11_and_cpp14' failed
make: *** [cpp11_and_cpp14] Error 1
```

I expect multi_threading.o to be created under folder ../advancedcppproject/multi_threading_example. However  multi_threading.o is created under  ../advancedcppproject.

Where as list_menu.o is correctly created under ../advancedcppproject/cpp11_and_cpp14_menu.

What is wrong?

Comment: By default gcc creates output file(s) in the current directory (pwd). Which is still the same where make was **started**. BTW. Make use of variables (incl. automatic) and patterns, as your makefile is practically unreadable/unmaintainable for a human being.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but I see that list_menu.o is created in its sub folder. Is there any way I can do that that multi_threading.o is also created under its respective folder?

Comment: Use gcc -o option.

Comment: Your example does not indicate that it is building `list_menu.o ` at all, and your makefile does not actually have a rule for it. We can improve this makefile, but you must do your part.

Comment: Thanks Beta, my only question is, with same file structure and same corresponding entries in Makefile, why do I see menu_list.o in its subfolder (../advancedcppproject/cpp11_and_cpp14_menu) and multi_threading.o in main folder (../advancedcppproject/)

Comment: Your fourth rule builds `multi_threading.o` in the directory where you run Make, because that' what `gcc` does by default *as @Matt already told you.* As for `menu_list.o`, you have no rule for that, I have no idea how it got there, you are not making an effort to be accurate.